# What alternative to github/gitorious/gitosis can I use on my server?

Tags: git, gitosis, gitorious

I would like to know what I can use as alternative as gitorious/gitosis on MY server, and that is able to link bug reports with source (like trac for subversion/...) ?

The server would be linux / osx powered.

Best regards.

Comment: What's wrong with gitorious/gitosis? Theses tools allow links with bug reports. Do you want a simpler solution? If you are the only user, you can directly use a SSH keypair without any git frontend tool.

Comment: What features do you want?  How many users?  What bug reporting tool do you want to use?

Comment: I tried Gitorious, it is a really great software, but I would prefer something simpler to deploy / maintain. I will be the only user, but I would like guests to browse code, and maybe publish bug reports. (any bug reporting tool is fine).

Comment: Also look at this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822550/looking-for-free-github-enterprise-fi-edition-alternative-for-private-installa][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822550/looking-for-free-github-enterprise-fi-edition-alternative-for-private-installa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used GitBlit http://gitblit.com/

It is a simple application that doesn't needs a lot of depencies from the OS. And the GUI is quite nice.

Answer (score 4):

Gitolite is amazing. You also get really good support from Sitaram (the author) on the IRC channel. I would highly recommend it.

Hope this helps.

FURTHER: Gitosis is no longer actively developed. If you were considering using it, gitolite is an easy replacement as it uses the same workflow for admin, etc.

Comment: Gitolite seems good, but I wasn't able to find a demonstration site.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out [RhodeCode](https://rhodecode.com), it supports git/hg/svn, has really nice installer that works on linux/windows (mac support coming soon)

We have issue tracker integration that works with redmine/jira/bugzilla etc. You can even configure smart commits with those and resolve issues by doing pushes.

disclosure: i created this project.

Answer (score 1):

You can git clone --bare onto any *nix based server to keep a copy of your repo (and all it's files) and all you have to do is manage ssh permissions as you would any other *nix management.

For others to browse your repo [via a web interface, this should help](http://gofedora.com/how-to-install-configure-gitweb/).

Git doesn't do bug reporting natively, but some add on software could help. Personally, I'd recommend a service like [lighthouse](http://lighthouseapp.com/) or [pivotal tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com).

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across [GitList](https://github.com/klaussilveira/gitlist) (PHP based) by Klaus Silveira. It's really simple to setup and has a nice UI. I have also written [an article](http://gofedora.com/insanely-awesome-web-interface-git-repos/) describing the setup process.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [GitLab](http://www.gitlab.org), it has merge requests to do code reviews, a wiki and an issue tracker. (disclosure: I'm a co-founder.